# Vue FullCalendar, setting click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar library for Vue https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue and I have a perfectly working calendar, but I can't get clicking on date/calendar events to work.

I have the calendar in the template:

```
<full-calendar @dateClick="handleDateClick" :config="config" :events="events"/></full-calendar>
```

and my vue code:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            events: [
              title: 'My Event',
              start: '2010-01-01'
            ],
            config: {
                defaultView: 'month',
                editable:true,
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    console.log(event)
                }
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
      handleDateClick(arg) {
        alert(arg.date)
      },
    },
}
```

This seems to match the docs but I'm not getting the alert. I'm just trying to make it so that I have the functionality in place so that I can tie each event click to a modal with that event's details.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors at all, that's one thing that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add selectable:true as the default is false. And you need the interactionPlugin as well.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectable
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index

```
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
config:{
...
selectable:true,
plugins:[interactionPlugin]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error that it can;'t find interaction. This is how I've imported fullcalendar now ```import FullCalendar from "vue-full-calendar";
```

Comment: How can I get the dependancy for it since I'm not using @fullcalendar/vue

Comment: Joao Oliveira, I also have a FullCalendar Vue question. I am attempting to connect an FC component to Firebase. Would you mind taking a look at the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382214/how-to-connect-firebase-to-fullcalendar-vue-component

Answer (score 4):

I have the following setup and it allows me to click and click and drag. Your code is only missing `@select=""`.

```
<template>
  <FullCalendar 
    defaultView="dayGridMonth" 
    :plugins="calendarPlugins" 
    :events="events"
    :selectable="true"
    @select="handleSelect"
    @clickDate="handleDateClick"
  />
</template>


<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';


export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  mounted(){

  },
  data () {
    return {
      events: [{title:'Something', start:'2019-09-12'}],
      calendarPlugins:[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    handleDateClick(e){
      console.log(e);
    },
    handleSelect(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='scss'>

  @import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
  @import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
  @import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
  @import '~@fullcalendar/list/main.css';

</style>
```

Comment: This does a console log if I click the day, whether there are events or not. I'm trying to make it so that I can click an actual event and get the info for it

Comment: Ok I actually got it working, but have you had issues with when the calendar first loads it only shows the month and the buttons? I have to hit the arrow and go back to see the current month view